# CassandraError: Undefined column name apparently due to case sensitivity despite consistent case in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sql, database, cassandra, cql

I have a Cassandra CQL statement being executed in a JavaScript file with several parameters including networkInterfaces TEXT:

```
client.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS testdb.networkData (latitude DOUBLE, longitude DOUBLE, allowsVoIP BOOLEAN, speed DOUBLE, uuid TEXT, timestamp TIMESTAMP PRIMARY KEY, networkType TEXT, carrierName TEXT, altitude DOUBLE, macAddress TEXT, publicIP TEXT, ssidLabel TEXT, networkInterfaces TEXT)", function (err, result) {
    if (!err){
        if ( result.rowLength > 0 ) {
            var data = result.rows[0];
            console.log("Total rows : "+ data.count);
        } else {
            console.log("No rows");
        }
    }else{
        console.log("count results err : "+err);
    }
});
```

The same case "networkInterfaces" is used in all other instances where networkInterfaces appears. This includes the code to insert data into the table:

```
// TODO: Save LAN interfaces as well
const recordCommand = 'INSERT INTO testdb.networkData (latitude, longitude, allowsVoIP, speed, uuid, timestamp, networkType, carrierName, altitude, macAddress, publicIP, ssidLabel, networkInterfaces) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)';
const params = [
    request.body.latitude,
    request.body.longitude,
    request.body.allowsVoIP,
    request.body.speed,
    request.body.uuid,
    request.body.timestamp,
    request.body.networkType,
    request.body.carrierName,
    request.body.altitude,
    request.body.macAddress,
    request.body.publicIP,
    request.body.ssidLabel,
    request.body.networkInterfaces
];

client.execute(recordCommand, params, { prepare: true }, function (error) {
    assert.ifError(error);
    //Inserted in the cluster
  });
```

And yet, when the command is executed, it says there is an unhandled error of the following:

> Error: Undefined column name networkinterfaces

The undefined column name appears to be a case mismatch, but all instances of networkInterfaces have the same case. Could there be some other issue?

Answer (score 2):

Cassandra will convert all table/column name in lower case by default. 
If case sensitive table/column name is required then enclose it in double quotes.
Check table details using `desc table_name`.

```
Eg:
Create table test(Column1 text primary key,"Column2" text);
 will result in cassandra table with 2 columns (column1 [Note all are lower case] and Column2 [C is uppercase])
```

Comment: I've reformatted the CREATE TABLE query as follows:  
  
`client.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS testdb.chatmessagingtable (sender TEXT, content TEXT, timestamp DOUBLE PRIMARY KEY)", function (err, result) {
...
});`  
  
And insert as follows:  
  
`const recordCommand = 'INSERT INTO testdb.networkData (latitude, longitude, "allowsVoIP", speed, uuid, timestamp, "networkType", "carrierName", altitude, "macAddress", "publicIP", "ssidLabel", "networkInterfaces") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)';`  
  
Now it's seeing the quotes as part of the key name

Comment: `Error: Undefined column name "allowsVoIP"` is what I'm getting in the console

Comment: I've reformatted my INSERT command string to `"INSERT INTO testdb.networkData (latitude, longitude, \"allowsVoIP\", speed, uuid, timestamp, \"networkType\", \"carrierName\", altitude, \"macAddress\", \"publicIP\", \"ssidLabel\", \"networkInterfaces\") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);"` and the console still says `Error: Undefined column name "allowsVoIP"`. I wonder why it's not stripping out the quotation marks.

Comment: I've added and `client.execute("DESC TABLE networkData;", function (err, result) {...});` and the result in the console is `no viable alternative at input 'DESC' ([DESC]...)`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample to correct your script. Here my keyspace name is yupoint.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS yupoint.user (
    id text,
    login text,
    password text,
    firstname text,
    lastname text,
    email text,
    activated boolean,
    lang_key text,
    activation_key text,
    reset_key text,
    reset_date timestamp,
    authorities set<text>,;
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS yupoint.user_by_login (
    login text,
    id text,
    PRIMARY KEY(login, id)
);
```

Now change use your keyspace and create some records.

> use yupoint;

```
yupoint>INSERT INTO user (id, login, password , firstname, lastname ,email ,activated ,lang_key, activation_key, authorities)
VALUES('3','admin','$2a$10$gSAhZrxMllrbgj/kkK9UceBPpChGWJA7SYIb1Mqo.n5aNLq1/oRrC','','Administrator','admin@localhost',true,'en','', {'ROLE_USER', 'ROLE_ADMIN'});

yupoint>INSERT INTO user_by_login (login, id)
VALUES('admin','3');
```

Comment: I've added a USE command as follows:

`client.execute("USE testdb", function (err, result) {
...
    });`

And have also edited the CREATE TABLE statements:

`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS testdb.networkData (latitude DOUBLE, longitude DOUBLE, \"allowsVoIP\" BOOLEAN, speed DOUBLE, uuid TEXT, timestamp TIMESTAMP, \"networkType\" TEXT, \"carrierName\" TEXT, altitude DOUBLE, \"macAddress\" TEXT, \"publicIP\" TEXT, \"ssidLabel\" TEXT, \"networkInterfaces\" TEXT,  PRIMARY KEY(timestamp));`

This did not resolve the quotes issue described in the thread on the other answer.

Comment: Try using snakecase. example: snake_case

Comment: I've switched to snake_case: `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS testdb.networkData (latitude DOUBLE, longitude DOUBLE, allows_voip BOOLEAN, speed DOUBLE, uuid TEXT, timestamp TIMESTAMP, network_type TEXT, carrier_name TEXT, altitude DOUBLE, mac_address TEXT, public_ip TEXT, ssid_label TEXT, network_interfaces TEXT,  PRIMARY KEY(timestamp));` and `INSERT INTO testdb.networkData (latitude, longitude, allows_voip, speed, uuid, timestamp, network_type, carrier_name, altitude, mac_address, public_ip, ssid_label, network_interfaces) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);`. It cant find allows_voip

Comment: The same holds true even after changing the table name to snake_case `networkData` to `network_data`

Answer (score 0):

All identifiers (table names, column names, etc) in Cassandra are **case-insensitive** unless you enclose them in quotes **every time you reference them**.  [DataStax documentation on this](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/ucase-lcase_r.html)

Because this tends to be tedious, most people use snake_case to name tables and columns like `network_data` and `network_type`. If you do enclose in quotes, these identifiers will continue to appear in quotes in all `DESCRIBE` output:

```
cqlsh:testdb> DESCRIBE TABLES;
table1  table2  network_data  "networkData"  table5
```

I've adjusted your queries to use uppercase and have tested this locally with success:

```
const createTable = (
  `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS testdb."networkData" (
    latitude DOUBLE, 
    longitude DOUBLE, 
    "allowsVoIP" BOOLEAN, 
    speed DOUBLE, 
    uuid TEXT, 
    timestamp TIMESTAMP PRIMARY KEY, 
    "networkType" TEXT, 
    "carrierName" TEXT, 
    altitude DOUBLE, 
    "macAddress" TEXT, 
    "publicIP" TEXT, 
    "ssidLabel" TEXT, 
    "networkInterfaces" TEXT)`
);

const recordCommand = (
  `INSERT INTO testdb."networkData" (
    latitude, 
    longitude, 
    "allowsVoIP", 
    speed, 
    uuid, 
    timestamp, 
    "networkType",
    "carrierName", 
    altitude, 
    "macAddress", 
    "publicIP", 
    "ssidLabel", 
    "networkInterfaces"
  ) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)`
);

const params = [
  request.body.latitude,
  request.body.longitude,
  request.body.allowsVoIP,
  request.body.speed,
  request.body.uuid,
  request.body.timestamp,
  request.body.networkType,
  request.body.carrierName,
  request.body.altitude,
  request.body.macAddress,
  request.body.publicIP,
  request.body.ssidLabel,
  request.body.networkInterfaces,
];

const selectData = `SELECT * FROM testdb."networkData"`;

client.connect()
  .then(() => client.execute(createTable))
  .then(() => client.execute(recordCommand, params, { prepare: true }))
  .then(() => client.execute(selectData))
  .then(result => {
    let count = result.rows.length
    if (count > 0)
      console.log(`Total rows : ${count}`)
    else console.log("No rows")
  })
  .catch(error => console.log(error));
```